# Multiple Lookup field , how to return better deliminators using object model?

Tags: lookup-column, splistitem

I have a multiple lookup field, and when I do this:

```
string myValue = oItem["MyLookupField"];
```

I get this string back:

[id];#[displayText];#[id];#[displayText]

or a real example:

"5;#C3;#15;#P3"

as you can see not the most logical string to split. Surely there must be a better way to get a splitable string back from sharepoint for a lookup field.

I would expect something like:

"5;C3|15;P3" (for example)

Anyone know how to get a better string back for a lookup field?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Instead of parsing them manually, try using the SPFieldLookupValue class instead:

[MSDN: SPFieldLookupValue](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.spfieldlookupvalue.aspx)

or the SPFieldMultiChoiceValue class:

[MSDN: SPFieldMultiChoiceValue](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.spfieldmultichoicevalue.aspx)

Comment: I happen to have written an article on this very subject a few moments ago. :) http://tsstsst.com/?p=44

Answer (score -1):

The delimiter cannot be changed and is found in the SPFieldMultiChoiceValue.Delimiter property.

Answer (score -3):

you can write own function like this

var Result = Regex.Split(data, ";#", RegexOptions.ExplicitCapture)
               .ToList().aggregate((x,y)=>x+";"+y+"|");

This solve your problem

Comment: -1 For that to work you have to know the delimiter